# Filter Queries in Get Items on Recurrence Flow

Tags: filter, power-automate, power-platform

I'm pretty new to Power Platform. I have an use case scenario where the flow runs once in a day, It compares today with the revision date from SP List - 30 days i.e Today's date >= [Revision days] - 30 days.

The Get items ofcourse processes all the items everyday even for the list items which already satisfied the condition. I want to restrict that, Let me know how it can be done.

I'm completely clueless on how to proceed.

Thanks,
Sid

Answer (score 1):

The **Get items** connector has the ability to add a filter in OData.

So, if you want to delete item depending a date, you can do that:

```
Created lt 'addDays(utcnow(), -30)'
```

Feel free to change the "Created" column by your "revision date" column.

[image: query]
[image: response]

Comment: Thanks for the quick revert. Actually my scenario is that,  Revision Date (Column in SP) - 30 days <= Today's date is that the condition i have in my flow. But i couldn't think of expression to write in the Filter Query to reduce the number of iteration or to not check the already processed items.

Comment: So, create a calculated column in SharePoint to get a date column with the value "[RevisionDate] - 30" and use an OData filter to this new column!

Comment: Calculated column should not be created so i rearranged the expression and applied the filter :)

Answer (score 0):

I have written the Filter data query like,

```
ReviewDate le formatDateTime(addDays(utcNow(), +30), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```